# Is the topology induced by the bases of a finite-dimensional real vector space equal to the topology induced by the norms?

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, vector-spaces, continuity, normed-spaces

It is well known that all norms on a $n$-dimensional real vector space induce the same topology (e.g. John Lee, Introduction to Smooth Manifolds, 2nd edition, Example 1.24). However, bases induce a "natural" topolgy, too: Let $(v_1,\ldots,v_n)$ be a basis, then we can define a topolgy by requiring that the isomorphism
\begin{align}
\Phi\colon\mathbf{R}^n&\to V\\
(x_1,\ldots,x_n)&\mapsto\sum_{i=1}^nx_iv_i
\end{align}
(and its inverse) are continuous: That is, $U\subset V$ is open if and only if $\Phi^{-1}(U)$ is open. One can show that the topology doesn't depend on the basis by using the fact that all linear maps from $\mathbf{R}^n$ to $\mathbf{R}^n$ are continuous, $L(\mathbf{R}^n,\mathbf{R}^n)\subset C(\mathbf{R}^n,\mathbf{R}^n)$.

**My question is**: Is the topology induced by the bases of a finite dimensional real vector space equal to (or contained in) the topology induced by the norms?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Let $\Phi : \mathbb R^n \to V$ be a linear isomorphism and $\lVert - \rVert$ be a norm on $\mathbb R^n$. Then $\lVert v \rVert_\phi = \lVert \Phi^{-1}(v) \rVert$ defines a norm on $V$. Clearly the norm-topology induced by $\lVert - \rVert_\phi$ is the same as the topology obtained by transferring the open sets in $\mathbb R^n$ via $\Phi$ to $V$.

Answer (score 0):

It's the same topology, since it is induced by the norm$$\left\|\sum_{i=1}^nx_iv_1\right\|=\sqrt{\sum_{i=1}^nx_i^{\,2}}.$$And this is true because, with respect to this norm, both $\Phi$ and its inverse are continuous.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: Yes.

**Notation**: If $X$ is a normed vector space, $x\in X$ and $0< r$, $B(x,r)=\{y\in X:|x-y|<r\}$ is the open ball with center $x$ and radius $r$.

**Lemma**: Let $V$ and $W$ be vector spaces over a subfield $F$ of $\mathbf{C}$ and let
\begin{equation}
W\ni w\mapsto\|w\|\in[0,\infty)
\end{equation}
be a norm. If $A\colon V\to W$ is a vector space isomorphism,
\begin{equation}
V\ni v\mapsto\|v\|:=\|A(v)\|\in[0,\infty)
\end{equation}
is a norm on $V$ and
\begin{equation}
B(A(v),r)=A(B(v,r)).
\end{equation}

**Corollary**: Let $V$ be a $n$-dimensional real vector space with a norm $V\ni v\mapsto\|v\|\in[0,\infty)$. If $T$ is the topology induced by the norm and $T'$ is the topolgy induced by the isomorphism $\Phi$ defined in my question, $T=T'$.

**Proof**:
From the Lemma we know that the norm on $V$ and the isomorphism $\Phi$ induce a norm on $\mathbf{R}^n$. Since all norms on $\mathbf{R}^n$ are equivalent, the topology on $\mathbf{R}^n$ induced by this norm is the standard topology. Thus, if $U\subset V$, the following statements are equivalent:

- $U\in T$.
- For each $v\in U$, there is $0<r$ such that $B(v,r)\subset U$.
- For each $x\in\Phi^{-1}(U)$, there is $0<r$ such that $B(\Phi(x),r)=\Phi(B(x,r))\subset U$.
- For each $x\in\Phi^{-1}(U)$, there is $0<r$ such that $B(x,r)\subset\Phi^{-1}(U)$.
- $\Phi^{-1}(U)$ is open/contained in the standard topology of $\mathbf{R}^n$.
- $U\in T'$.

Q.E.D.